# Post content blank after disabling Yoast SEO

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm trying to disable the Yoast SEO plugin from a very simple site with a custom theme. After disabling the plugin, posts do not have any content -- titles work, just `the_content` is empty. Pages are fine. If I re-enable the plugin, the post content comes back. The problem does not appear if I switch to one of the default Twenty* themes.

It seems like something is messing up the `$post` data early on, logging from the `the_content` filter at all priorities yields an empty string. Error logs are empty. My guess is something calls a Yoast function or filter somewhere, but I haven't found anything yet.

WordPress is a clean v4.7.5, Yoast SEO is v4.8 (both latest versions, fresh installs). The only other active plugin is Advanced Custom Fields Pro. I'm able to recreate this on multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the single-post.php template was missing a call to `the_post()`. Since that function initializes all the postdata used by functions like `the_content()`, WordPress had nothing to display.

As for Yoast SEO, I'm guessing it calls `the_post()` somewhere early on which would populate the WordPress global variables. If the theme was written with Yoast SEO enabled, no one would ever have noticed the omission.